# Craft rich text field excerpt with slice and raw breaks when cut inside double tags

Tags: templating, twigextension

I got a rich text field.
I made an excerpt with `striptags` `slice` and `raw` twig functions.
It works fine most of the time (`raw` close tags when `slice` cuts inside a `<p>`).

```
<div>{{ textBlock.text | striptags("<p><br><div><li><em>") | slice(0, 275) | raw }}...</div>
```

But sometimes it completely breaks and put plenty of empty tags anywhere :

[image]

I noticed that it happened when the original text is cut in the middle of double tags like :
`<p><em>Some text cut by slice function here</em></p>`

Real bug no ?

Answer (score 2):

Raw doesn't close tags tags for you, it just allows them to be processed rather than printed only.

The only reason you are seeing closing tags I'm guessing is because your inspector (chrome/safari) is adding them in. Do "view source" to see the real output.

Your problem here is just rogue open tags